# Inserting id into MYSQL table for multiple image upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, upload

I currently have a form that creates an item in a database then in the next step it allows the user to upload multiple images for that listing both sections work on their own but i need to be able to insert the $cid from the first page into the query for the image upload to identify which listing it corresponds to

Here is the page to allow the user to upload multiple images

```
<?php require_once 'config.php';

// Start the session
session_start();

// Require the classes for the page
require_once '../../assets/imageClass.php';

// create a new object class
$objects = new imageClass();

// set page variables
$path = '../';
$title = 'image upload';
$replace = 'content';
$message = '';



// Connect to the database


if(isset($_POST['image_upload'])){

        // Filter all of the $_POST data
        $objects->filterEverything($_POST);

        // Declare shorthand for the id value if there is $_POST data
        $cid = $objects->clean['cid'];
    }
    else{
            // Filter all of the $_GET data
        $objects->filterEverything($_GET);

        // Declare shorthand for the id value if there is $_GET data
        $cid = $objects->clean['cid'];
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autoways Image Upload</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >   

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="page-title" >Upload images</h1>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name='imageform' role="form" id="imageform" method="post" action="ajax.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Please Choose Image: </p>
                    <input class='file' multiple="multiple" type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" id="images" placeholder="Please choose your image">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cid;?>" />
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="loader" style="display: none;">
                    Please wait image uploading to server....
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="image_upload" id="image_upload" class="btn"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div id="uploaded_images" class="uploaded-images">
            <div id="error_div">
            </div>
            <div id="success_div">
            </div>

        </div>

        <a href="../index.php">I have finished uploading images</a>
        <?php echo $cid; ?>

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id='base_path' value="<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the upload function

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$data = array();
if( isset( $_POST['image_upload'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['images'] )){
    //get the structured array
    $images = restructure_array(  $_FILES );
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }


    foreach ( $images as $key => $value){
        $i = $key+1;
        //create directory if not exists
        if (!file_exists('images')) {
            mkdir('images', 0777, true);
        }
        $image_name = $value['name'];
        //get image extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        //assign unique name to image
        $name = $i*time().'.'.$ext;
        //$name = $image_name;
        //image size calcuation in KB
        $image_size = $value["size"] / 1024;
        $image_flag = true;
        //max image size
        $max_size = 512;
        if( in_array($ext, $allowedExts) && $image_size < $max_size ){
            $image_flag = true;
        } else {
            $image_flag = false;
            $data[$i]['error'] = 'Maybe '.$image_name. ' exceeds max '.$max_size.' KB size or incorrect file extension';
        } 

        if( $value["error"] > 0 ){
            $image_flag = false;
            $data[$i]['error'] = '';
            $data[$i]['error'].= '<br/> '.$image_name.' Image contains error - Error Code : '.$value["error"];
        }

        if($image_flag){
            move_uploaded_file($value["tmp_name"], "images/".$name);
            $src = "images/".$name;
            $dist = "images/thumbnail_".$name;
            $data[$i]['success'] = $thumbnail = 'thumbnail_'.$name;

            thumbnail($src, $dist, 200);
            $sql="INSERT INTO images (`id`, `original_image`, `thumbnail_image`, `ip_address`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$thumbnail', '$ip');";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            } 



        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {
    $data[] = 'No Image Selected..';
}



function restructure_array(array $images)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
                $result[$i][$k] = $val[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}



function thumbnail($src, $dist, $dis_width = 100 ){

    $img = '';
    $extension = strtolower(strrchr($src, '.'));
    switch($extension)
    {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($src);
            break;
        case '.png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($src);
            break;
    }
    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);




    $dis_height = $dis_width * ($height / $width);

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dis_width, $dis_height);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dis_width, $dis_height, $width, $height);


    $imageQuality = 100;

    switch($extension)
    {
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                imagejpeg($new_image, $dist, $imageQuality);
            }
            break;

        case '.gif':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                imagegif($new_image, $dist);
            }
            break;

        case '.png':
            $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);
            $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

            if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                imagepng($new_image, $dist, $invertScaleQuality);
            }
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($new_image);
}
```

Comment: Where do you need `$cid` - What listing do you mean?

Comment: I need to get the value of $cid into the database where the image is uploaded and its details stored in the database so that i have the id of the listing attached to the uploaded image to use

Comment: Ahm... and your database can store this information? - then you only have to do this: `$sql="INSERT INTO images (\`id\`, **\`listing\`**, \`original_image\`, \`thumbnail_image\`, \`ip_address\`) VALUES (NULL, **'". $_POST["cid"] ."'**, '$name', '$thumbnail', '$ip');";` But consider about making some security tests to ensure that there won't be any SQL-injection.

Comment: I have created the table and made the changes that you suggested but it stops inserting into the database

Comment: Any error texts? (the \** is only to mark you the important changes)

Comment: No error texts just doesn't insert into the database ??

Comment: So what is the script doing and at what point stops it? - Please show me your $sql.

Comment: It uploads the image itself into the upload folder but nothing into the database the sql is $sql="INSERT INTO images (`id`, `listingId`, `original_image`, `thumbnail_image`, `ip_address`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $_POST["cid"] . "', '$name', '$thumbnail', '$ip');"; @Johannes

Comment: Ok, you might have to change `'". $_POST["cid"] ."'` to `'$_POST["cid"]'`. I'm used to make sql at every time with `"...'". ."'..."`

Comment: There has to be an error somewhere otherwise it would work. Maybe turn back to your old code and change it again carefully. Can't help you more, I'm sorry...

Comment: Thanks for the help it seems to be the $_POST['cid'] that stops the insert as if i just set the value to check it inserts with the changed value just a question would i have to create a var in the upload script to store the $_POST data then use the var to insert? @Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

Please used **extract($_REQUEST)** on the top of each file. This function make post and get variables to global variables which can be used if you include the file or call another file.
Then echo **$cid**.

For the insert function used this.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO images (`id`,`listing`,`original_image`,`thumbnail_image`,`ip_address`) VALUES (NULL, $cid, '$name', '$thumbnail', '$ip');";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: When you say the top of each file do you mean within the <?php?> tags ?? or where exactly? and which file

Comment: <?php extract($_REQUEST); ?>. This two files.